# Difference between base-promoted and base-catalysed

Tags: reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds, terminology

Why is halogenation of ketones in base described as being "base-promoted" and not "base-catalysed"?

If the reaction is not "catalyzed" then how is the base used up?

Comment: For example, the base used in idoform reaction did not get regenerated. Therefore, it is needed as a reactant, not as a catalyst. Thus, it is a "base promoted" reaction, not "base catalysed."

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketone_halogenation The second image shows you the mechanism, and why the base is not a catalyst

Comment: Does "base-promoted" simply mean that the mechanism requires base? Base-catalyzed means that the base is regenerated during the reaction. The base in the aldol condensation is catalytic. In the Claisen condensation or saponification the base needs to be stoichiometric in that it is consumed during the reaction by deprotonation. IMO both sets of conditions may be considered base-promoted.